# Soft coding for loop to change file output of geoprocessing tool to create identical shapefiles for multiple years

Tags: arcpy

I would like to perform the arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management tool to copy a template shapefile several times to create the same shapefile for multiple years.
I would like the output files to be "neb_precip_2008.shp","neb_precip_2009.shp","neb_precip_2010.shp"... up until 2016. I understand it should be looped through, but I want to learn how to do this without a list. I'm still in the beginning stage of python learning.

```
try:
  immport arcpy
  from arcpy import env
  env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Documents"

  out_path = r"C:\Users\Documents"
  out_name = "neb_precip_2008.shp"
  geometry_type = "POINT"
  template = "practice_dataPrecip2008Readings.shp"
  has_m = "DISABLED"
  has_z = "DISABLED"

spatial_reference = arcpy.Describe("C:\Users\Documents\practice_dataPrecip2008Readings.shp").spatialReference

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type, template, has_m, has_z, spatial_reference)

except:
  print "Script failed to complete"
  print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
```

Comment: Even though you are a beginner, looping through a list is not only one of the more common tasks as a Python programmer, but one of the more simple and explicit ways to store data

Comment: Please leave the try/except statements out of code snippets that you are testing prior to posting because they can mask error messages that might be helpful when debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a number loop using a range.

Try:

```
for year in range(2008, 2017):
  out_name = "neb_precip_{}.shp".format(year)
  arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type, template, has_m, has_z, spatial_reference)
```

(As an aside, I tend to like lists since they are more explicit.)

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not use while loops, but for the chance that you find it easier in this case without using a list

```
year = 2008
while year < 2017:
    out_name = "neb_precip_{}.shp".format(year)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type, template, has_m, has_z, spatial_reference)
    year+=1
```